# How to set default emacs background and foreground colors?

Tags: emacs

In My `.emacs` file, I have the following:

```
(set-foreground-color "#E0DFDB")
(set-background-color "#102372")
```

When I start up emacs, the color scheme for the default emacs window is correct but all new windows start with the default color scheme of white back grounds and black foreground. Can Anyone point Me in the direction of how to get emacs to set My preferred color scheme in all new windows? [Note: If I do `M-x load-file ~/.emacs` after opening a new window, the colors are set the way I want but doing so manually every time I want to open a new window is distracting/annoying.]

Comment: You might want to take a look at ColorTheme (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme) for a more complete solution.

Comment: @TiloWiklund The link is broken.

Comment: This only sets for current frame. How about for all?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Add the following to your `.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(foreground-color . "#E0DFDB"))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(background-color . "#102372"))
```

You might want to look at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameParameters and the links therein.

Comment: Perfect. What I did was set `(foreground-color . "color-232")` and `(background-color . "color-231")` to get the same color scheme as emacs-gtk

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for Doom emacs though. Unrelated to this specific question I know, but how would one achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to emacs. Use Color themes to better suit your environment.
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorThemes

Comment: Broken links. Please fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Another excellent method of color implementation for is available here:

http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/s0243221/emacs/

I found it convenient to call the colors by names rather than the HEX codes.